# Wi-fi network adapter ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, adapter

I just install ubuntu and shows me that I have no wi-fi Adapter. I have 5.11.0-38-generic as kernal. I have the ubuntu 20.04 version. I have tried to see the software & updates and I can not see it. I have tried to disable the change the secure boot state also. What can I do?

sudo lshw -C network

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh70j.png

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. Is it a USB or a built-in adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 It is built in because is a laptop.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: @waltinator ready, I hope is ok now

Comment: Please copy/paste text instead of using pictures of text. One of your unlabeled images clearly shows the problem, and suggests a solution...but I can't copy text from an image to show you.

Comment: @waltinator if you want and if you have discord you can explain to me on discord

Comment: @waltinator `sudo lshw -C network` is useless. It doesn't have hw codes.

Comment: Most likely a newer kernel is needed.

Comment: @Pilot6 but if I will upgrade my kernal I will be able to keep my nvidia x Server?

Comment: Thank you ! I have update it the kernel but now I have an other problem.... :(